# Want to call API for 7 times by using tosca

Tags: tosca

I am trying to call API but due to lots of data, I'm not able to fetch all data in one call. I need to call API for 7 times to fetch all the data in TOSCA and every time I call api, in 1st call whatever data I'll get,  the same data should not come in the next call( duplicate data should not appear in the 2nd call and so on)

I want tosca to call api repeatedly untill it fetch all the data. I'm using SNOW API.

Comment: read this [ask]